# An explicit formula for some hadamard product

Tags: infinite-product

Is there an explicit formula for

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \Big(1- \dfrac{z}{\pi^{3/2}\;k^{3/2}}\Big) $$

?

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the power of $k$. For integer $k>0$, there are closed form formulae. For $k=3/2$, I did not find anything.

Comment: This is equivalent to finding the function whose reflection formula yields the $\Gamma$ function, just as the latter's reflection formula yields the sine and cosine functions.